# sql: sp_cursorexecute execute error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, execution

i have next code when user login in program:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1073741826
declare @p2 int
set @p2=180150003
declare @p5 int
set @p5=1
declare @p6 int
set @p6=8
declare @p7 int
set @p7=1
exec sp_cursorprepexec @p1 output,@p2 output,N'@P1 varchar(30)',N'
SELECT  US_WarningFlag, datediff(day, ISNULL(US_LastPassChange, convert(datetime, ''1900-01-01'',
 120)), GetDate()), ISNULL(US_PassExpireTime, -1), US_PassMinLength
FROM    dbo.UserList    
WHERE   US_UserID = @P1',@p5 output,@p6 output,@p7 output,'Userlogin'
select @p1, @p2, @p5, @p6, @p7<br/>
```

its complete with error:

> Msg 16902, Level 16, State 20, Procedure sp_cursorprepexec, Line 1
>       sp_cursorprepexec: The value of the parameter 'scrollopt' is invalid.

Do some one know, how fix that?

Answer (score 4):

Comment out the setting of @p1 and @p2, and set @p5 = 4097.
Also take out the html line-break at the end, if that's not a typo.

I take it you're looking at profile/trace results, at the RPC:Completed. Find the matching (via SPID) RPC:Starting, this should execute without any edits.

Comment: I had to add the RPC:Starting option to the trace Events Selection to find it, but once I did, i could execute the query in MSSMS unmodified